# Jenkins CI : podTemplate jenkinsfile unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, openshift

In Jenkins, I want to understand why "docker ps" is not running inside my container despite I redact my Jenkins file like this :

```
podTemplate(serviceAccount: 'jenkins', containers: [ 
    containerTemplate(
      name: 'docker', 
      image: 'docker', 
      resourceRequestCpu: '100m',
      resourceLimitCpu: '300m',
      resourceRequestMemory: '300Mi',
      resourceLimitMemory: '500Mi',
      command: 'cat', 
      privileged: true,
      ttyEnabled: true
    )
  ],

  volumes: [
    hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock')
  ]
  ) {
    node(POD_LABEL) {

        stage('Check running containers') {
            container('docker') {  
                sh 'hostname'
                sh 'hostname -i' 
                sh 'docker --version'
                sh 'docker ps'
            }
}
```

I have always this kind of message after I start my pipeline :
unix:///var/run/docker.sock.

Is the docker daemon running?
Thanks

It must have something like the result of a PS running with docker command.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you run Jenkins inside a docker container, you must install docker inside.

Best way create a new Dockerfile and install docker inside.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

ARG HOST_UID=1004
ARG HOST_GID=999

USER root
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add - && \
    add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") $(lsb_release -cs) stable" && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose  \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose  \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose \
    && curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - 
RUN echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list \
    && apt-get -y update \
    && apt install -y kubectl

RUN usermod -u $HOST_UID jenkins
RUN groupmod -g $HOST_GID docker
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins
```

For the sake of clarity if you deploy to Kubernetes or use docker-compose, you will need also kubectl and docker-compose inside your container. If not you can remove the installation from Dockerfile above.

Comment: Even if i want to run docker inside a pod via jenkins it can work using this : 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/examples/dind.groovy
but i want to use another way in order to simplify my jenkinsfile code

Comment: How will you run docker in Jenkins if docker is not installed on the Jenkismachine. There are always several ways to do. I just posted you one. You did not indicate where your Jenkins is running. I told you where the error comes from and how you can fix it.